Can I access the information under "My Items" in my LinkedIn profile via the LinkedIn API?
I am working on a project that requires me to pull some of my saved information like saved posts under my personal LinkedIn profile.
I tried searching the LinkedIn API documentation but I can't find any information on this. If you can't currently do this with the LinkedIn API, how do I request the ability to do so?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
